# Error while installing azimuth in meteor project

Tags: meteor, azimuth

After Installation of meteor and creation of meteor project I run the following command:

sudo meteor add azimuth-views-foundation

I get the following error, please suggest what am I missing:

> => Errors while parsing arguments:
>                                                  While adding package azimuth-views-foundation: error: no such package

Comment: same issue with bootstrap as well

Comment: meteor packages naming is changed, Now the package names are like `author:packagename` example `iron:router` the packages that you're trying  to add are out-dated , to find the latest packages go to atmospherejs.com   there you find pacakages which are actively maintained and few packages like `moment` and `bootstrap` also have official packages from the respective teams

Comment: updated package https://atmospherejs.com/mcrider/azimuth-views-foundation Is this the package you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look into this search on [Atmosphere Azimuth](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=azim), there is not such package named `azimuth-views-foundation`

Try with `meteor add mcrider:azimuth-views-foundation` instead.